# TYPO3 How to rename default language in introduction package?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have created multiple languages for my root package. I have noticed that the first language is called default. Is there any possibility to rename it?
[image: check this]

p.s: in frontend it looks like this, I want to change it as well:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PageTS option `mod.SHARED.defaultLanguageLabel` to change this:

```
mod {
    SHARED {
        defaultLanguageLabel = English
    }
}
```

See the explanation for [`defaultLanguageLabel` in the TYPO3 TSconfig reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/Mod.html#defaultlanguagelabel).

Comment: Great! This overwrites the default in backend but not in the page. In backend I have now English(default) but in the real page it is still default

Comment: What do you mean with that? The frontend output is completely up to you and not affected by any setting.

Comment: I have updated the post, look the screenshot there. I would like to change or delete default language. Sorry I am pretty new

Comment: OK, but still this output is completely up to you. Please also add/link the code which builds the language navigation to your post.

Comment: I am using intrudation package and bootstrap_package

Comment: In this case you'll need to copy and adjust the [partial for the language menu](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/1e4d71edb7bed59e77bbd57c066f73713a7a6f4b/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Navigation/Language.html). Alternatively you can use the [LanguageMenuViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/3.0.0/Page/LanguageMenuViewHelper.html) from the VHS extension which has an `defaultLanguageLabel` argument.